# Caching/storage strategies for implementing a word dictionary in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

I am looking at using a spell checker for my GAE app and we have an algorithm already for spell checking, but I'm trying to figure out how to best store and load dictionary files for best performance.

I am considering the following strategies:

1. Place the dictionary data in a text file(s) in local app engine storage and load/read them using standard IO methods (`open()`,`read()`,etc)
2. Place the dictionary data in GCS and load/read using GCS IO methods
3. Place the dictionary data in an `ndb.model()` and load/cache information

One cache I don't quite understand is the context cache -- is this cache that is attached to a given instance? I.e. if I have a resident instance that is spun up, can I go ahead and load the dictionary data into the instance's RAM and thus accessing data should be extremely fast (microsecond vs millisecond seek/get times)? The dictionary data will probably be a sharded list of some sort that we'll optimize for performance. Are there other data storage methods/structures I'm not considering here that may be more appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: how big is the dict?

Answer (score 0):

Cache (or its full name memcache) isn't exactly RAM but similar. When used with NDB it acts like a buffer. When you do writes it writes to the Memcache first then to the DB. Though this may sound slower its not, as writes to the DB take a while before they are accessible. When it reads it checks memcache, if it exists then it uses that info otherwise it pulls from the DB, stores it in Memcache then gives you the data. Just like RAM though its volatile, thus you cannot guaranty information is always acceptable, its limited (depending on what type of instance you have) and can be flush with no warning or reason. You can read more here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache

Ultimately Memcahe will be the fastest and most accessible as it it shared amongst all your instances, so if one instance pulls some data from the datastore then all of them can access it quickly. Even if its not in memcache it is still the fastest of all the options, as the others ones will fill up your memory and may cause errors and performance issues.